# integrating Audit4J in dropwizard Application

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, dropwizard, audit4j

Has anyone had success integrating Audit4J into their dropwizard application? I am working on a project where we have to implement some audit logging, and stumbled upon Audit4J which seem to be nice, I just can't figure out how to make it work in my DW application.
So wanted to hear if anyone has had any success making it work?

I am trying with the example in the documentation but getting the error even I put an "audit4j.conf.yml" in the Resource folder.

```
Audit4j:INFO Loading Configurations...
enter code hereAudit4j:WARN Initial confguration file not found. 
Creating a new configuration file - audit4j.conf.yml
Audit4j:WARN Audit4j: Unable to find a solution for error: Unable to 
create configuration file.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /audit4j.conf.yml
```

Comment: Sounds like the file should be at the root of the working directory, not a resource.

Comment: FileNotFoundException means they are trying to access a file on the file system, not a resource.

Comment: I event created at root folder also stilll not able to make it work same error .....Please provide me some example

Comment: You created a `audit4j.conf.yml` at the root of the project?

Comment: yes, i  have created on the root folder. I am little new to dropwizard itself ... pls somebody provide an example where to define and how to load in dropwizard application.